# traversing orientdb graph, sql-traverse vs gremlin

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I want to model linked nodes data set:

`Node(A)----next---->Node(B)----next---->Node(C)`

applying SQL-Traverse:

```
traverse out('next') from Node(A)
```

will include Node(A) in result; A,B,C ,and this is the desired output, 
where as using gremlin:

```
g.('Node(A)').as('start').out('next').loop('start')
```

will only returns B,C ,

my question is how to emit Node A in gremlin , followed by other nodes, in the same order they were linked in, and i prefer the end result to be pipline; i.e. i tried aggregate(), but the problem with it is that it will  make me use the aggregated collection as a start point for a new pipline with new traverse, and i dont want this behavior, any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think `path` will do what you want:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).as('s').out().loop('s'){true}{true}.path()
==>[v[1], v[3]]
==>[v[1], v[2]]
==>[v[1], v[4]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[5]]
```

Comment: this a good workaround, but i am interested in the path of the last node, do you know how to get only the last visited path, or is there any pipe that emits the last node.

Comment: I'm sorry - i don't follow what you mean.  Can you ask your question in the context of my example above?  What would you want your output to be?

Comment: my data structrue is linked nodes, i.e. each vertex has only one edge with the next vertex, and in the example above every traversed vertext will output its path, so it will make more sense to only get the path of the last traversed vertex which will contain the whole train of vertices

Comment: Then just remove the "emit" closure (i.e. the second one) to loop.  By setting to `true` I'm telling it to emit all paths encountered in the pipe.